# Python - Webdriver - malware win32:evo-gen

Tags: python, selenium, malware

I'm starting coding with Python.
I've download Cromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and move it to my Anaconda paste.
I run `Pip install Selenium`
After that, i wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I got the error below because my Avast found malware "win32:evo-gen" and moved the file. Is it really a malware since I got the file from chromedriver.chromium.org? If not, how can I solve this issue?

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     71             cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
---> 72             self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     73                                             close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have been a false positive, please send it for check, it happened to me too a few hours ago.

Comment: I've download another day (same version) and worked fine! Thx @Luis Mauricio